# Why is the vector increasing its size to 10 when i am initialising its size to 5 and giving only 5 elements?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

So i was doing this question on vector where i had to take input and then reverse all the elements

```
int main() {

    int i,n,a;   
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> arr(n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin >> a;
        arr.push_back(a);
    } 
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code where i have mentioned the size as n of vector and pushing only n elements in it. But the output is coming out to be 0 0 0 0 0 for 5 elements. I guess that is because the vector has expanded its capacity to 10 and hence last 5 elements are printed which are obviously 0. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Because you used `arr.push_back(a);` instead of `arr[i] = a;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<int> arr(n);` creates a vector of size `n` from the start, all elements initialized to `int{}` aka zero. Then the loop adds `n` more elements via `push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<int> arr(n);`

Since you claim that `n = 5`, this line of code creates `arr = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

But then you run a loop 5 times, and add 5 more elements to your vector via `push_back`:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin >> a;
    arr.push_back(a); // <-- mistake
}
```

And then you print the first 5 elements (which are 0) via

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

*That is why, your output is `0 0 0 0 0`.*

**Solution:**

You should add those elements to the space you already reserved for your vector:

Replace `arr.push_back(a);` with `arr[i] = a;`

**Aside:**

> So i was doing this question on vector where i had to take input and
>   then reverse all the elements

`sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());` will not help you achieve this task.

**You should use [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):**

`reverse(arr.begin(), arr.end());`